# Remove text and hyperlinks then forward

Tags: vba, outlook, email-forwarding

EDIT: Added snippet of closer to actual string i'm trying to manipulate at the bottom of the post. It's not verbatim, removed key information, but i copied and pasted from the email that I'm trying to forward. Just trying to extract the table at in the middle and forward.

I want to delete specific text on an email that I've received, remove the hyperlinks, keep the formatting, and then forward to a specific address.

Basically, the email is structured as such:

> "Dear user,
>
> please find the relevant information below
>
> database: records
>   click here to view this online
>
> - Table header
> - Column Header
> - Record 1
> - Record 2
> - Record 3
> - ...
> - Final Record
>
> If you have trouble using the link above, paste this link in your address bar to go to the online database:
>
> somewebsite.database.net/tr/vuioahdf
>
> This is an automated email..."

I need to remove the text before the table, remove the hyperlinks, keep the formatting, and forward.

I tried the following.

```
Sub RemoveExpression()

Dim Insp As Inspector
Dim obj As Object

    Set Insp = Application.ActiveInspector
    Set obj = Insp.CurrentItem

    obj.Body = Replace(obj.Body, "Dear user, please find the relevant information below database: records click here to view this online - Table header " & _
                                    vbNewLine & "If you have trouble using the link above, paste this link in your address bar to go to the online database http://somewhere.database.net/tr/vuioahdf This is an automated email...", "")

    Set obj = Nothing
    Set Insp = Nothing

End Sub
```

It gives me an error about not defining an object, but this is something along the lines of what I'm looking to do. Remove some text before and after a table, remove the hyperlinks, and then forward to specific address. It might not be completely necessary to remove the hyperlinks, as it's mostly in the text before and after the table, but there is a hyperlink in the table header.

Email I'm trying to manipulate:

```html
Dear User,<br>
<br>
Please find below drawing received last week for project
<br> <br>
<b><u></u>Document Control: Projects<u></u></b><br>
Click <a href="somehwere.net" target="_blank">here</a> to see this report on the database.
<br> <br>
<div style="font-size:70%;font-family:Verdana,Helvetica,Geneva,sans-serif">
<div>
<table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
<tr style="background-color:#c4defb">
<td style="border-top:1px solid #55a0ef;border-bottom:1px solid #55a0ef">
<table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
<tr>
<td style="width:200px;padding:4px 8px;font-family:Helvetica Neue,Helvetica,Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:#505050;font-weight:normal;font-size:9pt">
<a style="font-family:Helvetica Neue,Helvetica,Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:#505050;font-weight:normal;font-size:9pt;text-decoration:none" href="somewhere.net" title="See this report" target="_blank">Full Report</a>
| <a style="font-family:Helvetica Neue,Helvetica,Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:#505050;font-weight:normal;font-size:9pt;text-decoration:none" href="somewhere.net" title="Edit all the Drawings shown below" target="_blank">Grid Edit</a>
</td>
<td style="width:200px;padding:4px 8px;font-family:Helvetica Neue,Helvetica,Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:#505050;font-weight:normal;font-size:9pt" align="right">
<span><label>Date Created</label> is during <label> &#39;last 2 wk&#39; </label> AND ...</span>    <span>11 Drawings</span>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
<table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
<thead style="display:table-header-group">
<tr>
<td style="font-family:Helvetica Neue,Helvetica,Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;border-left:1px solid #ccc;border-bottom:1px solid #ccc;background-color:#f6f9fd;padding:3px 4px;font-weight:bold;font-size:10pt;color:#111111"> </td>
<td align="right" style="font-family:Helvetica Neue,Helvetica,Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;border-left:1px solid #ccc;border-bottom:1px solid #ccc;background-color:#f6f9fd;padding:3px 4px;font-weight:bold;font-size:10pt;color:#111111"><div></div><span>Date Created</span><span></span></td>
<td style="font-family:Helvetica Neue,Helvetica,Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;border-left:1px solid #ccc;border-bottom:1px solid #ccc;background-color:#f6f9fd;padding:3px 4px;font-weight:bold;font-size:10pt;color:#111111"><span>Project Name</span><span></span></td>
<td style="font-family:Helvetica Neue,Helvetica,Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;border-left:1px solid #ccc;border-bottom:1px solid #ccc;background-color:#f6f9fd;padding:3px 4px;font-weight:bold;font-size:10pt;color:#111111"><span>Sub Project</span><span></span></td>
<td style="font-family:Helvetica Neue,Helvetica,Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;border-left:1px solid #ccc;border-bottom:1px solid #ccc;background-color:#f6f9fd;padding:3px 4px;font-weight:bold;font-size:10pt;color:#111111"><span>Project Description</span><span></span></td>
<td style="font-family:Helvetica Neue,Helvetica,Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;border-left:1px solid #ccc;border-bottom:1px solid #ccc;background-color:#f6f9fd;padding:3px 4px;font-weight:bold;font-size:10pt;color:#111111"><span>Drawing Number</span><span></span></td>
<td style="font-family:Helvetica Neue,Helvetica,Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;border-left:1px solid #ccc;border-bottom:1px solid #ccc;background-color:#f6f9fd;padding:3px 4px;font-weight:bold;font-size:10pt;color:#111111"><span>Revision</span><span></span></td>
<td style="font-family:Helvetica Neue,Helvetica,Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;border-left:1px solid #ccc;border-bottom:1px solid #ccc;background-color:#f6f9fd;padding:3px 4px;font-weight:bold;font-size:10pt;color:#111111"><span>Title</span><span></span></td>
<td style="font-family:Helvetica Neue,Helvetica,Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;border-left:1px solid #ccc;border-bottom:1px solid #ccc;background-color:#f6f9fd;padding:3px 4px;font-weight:bold;font-size:10pt;color:#111111"><span>Transmittal</span><span></span></td>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody style="display:table-row-group">
<tr>
<td nowrap style="border-left:1px solid #ccc;border-bottom:1px solid #ccc;padding:3px 4px;font-size:10pt;color:#111111"> </td>
<td style="font-family:Helvetica Neue,Helvetica,Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;border-left:1px solid #ccc;border-bottom:1px solid #ccc;padding:3px 4px;font-size:10pt;color:#111111" align="right">02-18-2016</td>
<td style="font-family:Helvetica Neue,Helvetica,Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;border-left:1px solid #ccc;border-bottom:1px solid #ccc;padding:3px 4px;font-size:10pt;color:#111111">Rig xxx</td>
<td style="font-family:Helvetica Neue,Helvetica,Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;border-left:1px solid #ccc;border-bottom:1px solid #ccc;padding:3px 4px;font-size:10pt;color:#111111">120</td>
<td style="font-family:Helvetica Neue,Helvetica,Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;border-left:1px solid #ccc;border-bottom:1px solid #ccc;padding:3px 4px;font-size:10pt;color:#111111">Structure</td>
<td style="font-family:Helvetica Neue,Helvetica,Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;border-left:1px solid #ccc;border-bottom:1px solid #ccc;padding:3px 4px;font-size:10pt;color:#111111">00813-121-000-001WM</td>
<td style="font-family:Helvetica Neue,Helvetica,Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;border-left:1px solid #ccc;border-bottom:1px solid #ccc;padding:3px 4px;font-size:10pt;color:#111111">0</td>
<td style="font-family:Helvetica Neue,Helvetica,Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;border-left:1px solid #ccc;border-bottom:1px solid #ccc;padding:3px 4px;font-size:10pt;color:#111111">REAR FRAME</td>
<td style="font-family:Helvetica Neue,Helvetica,Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;border-left:1px solid #ccc;border-bottom:1px solid #ccc;padding:3px 4px;font-size:10pt;color:#111111">02182016</td>
</tr>
<tr style="background-color:#f2f2f2">
<td nowrap style="border-left:1px solid #ccc;border-bottom:1px solid #ccc;padding:3px 4px;font-size:10pt;color:#111111"> </td>
<td style="font-family:Helvetica Neue,Helvetica,Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;border-left:1px solid #ccc;border-bottom:1px solid #ccc;padding:3px 4px;font-size:10pt;color:#111111" align="right">02-18-2016</td>
<td style="font-family:Helvetica Neue,Helvetica,Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;border-left:1px solid #ccc;border-bottom:1px solid #ccc;padding:3px 4px;font-size:10pt;color:#111111">Rig xxx</td>
<td style="font-family:Helvetica Neue,Helvetica,Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;border-left:1px solid #ccc;border-bottom:1px solid #ccc;padding:3px 4px;font-size:10pt;color:#111111">120</td>
<td style="font-family:Helvetica Neue,Helvetica,Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;border-left:1px solid #ccc;border-bottom:1px solid #ccc;padding:3px 4px;font-size:10pt;color:#111111">Structure</td>
<td style="font-family:Helvetica Neue,Helvetica,Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;border-left:1px solid #ccc;border-bottom:1px solid #ccc;padding:3px 4px;font-size:10pt;color:#111111">00813-121-000-000</td>
<td style="font-family:Helvetica Neue,Helvetica,Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;border-left:1px solid #ccc;border-bottom:1px solid #ccc;padding:3px 4px;font-size:10pt;color:#111111">0</td>
<td style="font-family:Helvetica Neue,Helvetica,Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;border-left:1px solid #ccc;border-bottom:1px solid #ccc;padding:3px 4px;font-size:10pt;color:#111111">REAR ASSEMBLY</td>
<td style="font-family:Helvetica Neue,Helvetica,Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;border-left:1px solid #ccc;border-bottom:1px solid #ccc;padding:3px 4px;font-size:10pt;color:#111111">01282016</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td nowrap style="border-left:1px solid #ccc;border-bottom:1px solid #ccc;padding:3px 4px;font-size:10pt;color:#111111"> </td>
<td style="font-family:Helvetica Neue,Helvetica,Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;border-left:1px solid #ccc;border-bottom:1px solid #ccc;padding:3px 4px;font-size:10pt;color:#111111" align="right">02-18-2016</td>
<td style="font-family:Helvetica Neue,Helvetica,Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;border-left:1px solid #ccc;border-bottom:1px solid #ccc;padding:3px 4px;font-size:10pt;color:#111111">Rig xxx</td>
<td style="font-family:Helvetica Neue,Helvetica,Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;border-left:1px solid #ccc;border-bottom:1px solid #ccc;padding:3px 4px;font-size:10pt;color:#111111">120</td>
<td style="font-family:Helvetica Neue,Helvetica,Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;border-left:1px solid #ccc;border-bottom:1px solid #ccc;padding:3px 4px;font-size:10pt;color:#111111">Structure</td>
<td style="font-family:Helvetica Neue,Helvetica,Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;border-left:1px solid #ccc;border-bottom:1px solid #ccc;padding:3px 4px;font-size:10pt;color:#111111">00813-121-000-001</td>
<td style="font-family:Helvetica Neue,Helvetica,Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;border-left:1px solid #ccc;border-bottom:1px solid #ccc;padding:3px 4px;font-size:10pt;color:#111111">0</td>
<td style="font-family:Helvetica Neue,Helvetica,Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;border-left:1px solid #ccc;border-bottom:1px solid #ccc;padding:3px 4px;font-size:10pt;color:#111111">REAR FRAME</td>
<td style="font-family:Helvetica Neue,Helvetica,Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;border-left:1px solid #ccc;border-bottom:1px solid #ccc;padding:3px 4px;font-size:10pt;color:#111111">01282016</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
</div>
<br>
If you have trouble using the link above, copy and paste the following Web address into the address bar of your browser:
<br>   <a href="somewhere.net" target="_blank">somewhere.net</a>
<br> <br>
This is an automated email from an online application. If you feel that you received this email in error, please contact the application's manager,
<a href="mailto:someone@projects.net" target="_blank">someone@projects.net</a>
</td></tr></table>
</div>
</font></div></table></table></div></div></body></html>
```

Answer (score 1):

The `Body` property of a `MailItem` that you received is read only. That's probably why you're getting an error. You need to forward the message, get the forwarded message, then manipulate it's `Body`.

If you received an email that had a bunch of stuff in it including one table and you wanted to forward just the table, you could use code like this

```
Public Sub ForwardTableOnly()

    Dim olMail As MailItem
    Dim lTblStart As Long, lTblEnd As Long

    Set olMail = ActiveInspector.currentItem.Forward

    lTblStart = InStr(1, olMail.HTMLBody, "<table")
    lTblEnd = InStr(lTblStart, olMail.HTMLBody, "</table")

    olMail.HTMLBody = Mid$(olMail.HTMLBody, lTblStart, lTblEnd - lTblStart + 1)
    olMail.Display

End Sub
```

It finds where the table is in the `HTMLBody` property and gets rid of everything else. That works, but it's more complicated than that. If you want to keep the table plus some of the other stuff, you'll have more complicated string manipulation. And if the formatting is important to you, you'll have another problem. It's likely that the table is formatted with styles that are defined further up in the `HTMLBody` along with a bunch of other styles. That's even more string manipulation. But string manipulation is easy enough if not tedious and boring.

The pertinent points are: call the Forward method and assign the resulting MailItem to an object variable. Then set that object's `HTMLBody` property to whatever you want. In this example, I use the `.Display` property to show the message. You'll want to use `.To` and `.Send` probably rather than `.Display`.

Comment: Wow, this worked so well!
Only one problem: the HTML probably has it's own definition of the table (as you mentioned) as this Macro only pulls the header. If it could pull the entire table, it would be working great!

Comment: Sorry for the late reply!!!
Also, this is so close! But, I took a closer look at the code source of the table. Apparently, it's 2 tables. The "header" is actually a table on top. Then, there is a second table that has the information that I am most interested in forwarding. This Macro got so close, but it did not delete the text before the table and included it up until then. Sorry to pester, but where can I find some good string manipulation for Macros? Thanks for all of your help!

Comment: If you post the actual string (or a close example) I can give you more specifics. For string manipulation, search for `Mid`, `Instr`, and `Replace`. They'll get you most of the way. There's also a regex library if you're good at that.

Comment: I went ahead and added the snippet of what I am trying to manipulate and email forward. Hopefully, that's enough to work with and see if we can extract just the table. You're help has been great! Make sure to run the snippet so you can see what I'm seeing.